# The script is running from terminal but not from crontab?

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, cron

The script is running from terminal but not from crontab.The script code and error i am getting is written below :

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['touch','yahoo.txt'])
```

**Error from Crontab mail**

```
From root@vps.server.com  Mon Jul 22 21:10:05 2013
Return-Path: <root@vps.server.com>
Received: from vps.server.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by vps.server.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) with ESMTP id r6MHA3ll002017
    for <root@vps.server.com>; Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:03 +0400
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by vps.server.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6MHA1sr002016
    for root; Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:01 +0400
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:01 +0400
Message-Id: <201307221710.r6MHA1sr002016@vps.server.com>
From: root@vps.server.com (Cron Daemon)
To: root@vps.server.com
Subject: Cron <root@vps> cd /root/; python mkdir.py
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `cron` uses a different environment than what you have in your shell. Try passing in the absolute path to `yahoo.txt` to see if that helps

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i got you point but script should create "yahoo.txt" in directory the script is.

Comment: Perhaps try `subprocess.call(['/path/to/touch', 'yahoo.txt')`?

Comment: @KapilaClan Only if the script is in the users home directory. The script should create `${HOME}/yahoo.txt`...

Comment: @twalberg the script is in /root/ so it should create "yahoo.txt" there ????user is root

Comment: @KapilaClan If the `cron` job is being run by the `root` user, then, yes `HOME=/root` for the environment the job is run in, and unless the job specifically changes directory, all relative path names will be interpreted relative to that location. In this case, the script is in the users home directory (as opposed to, e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a literal carriage return in your command line (created by some errant editor or a Windows user or some such):

```
$ python nosuchfile.py
python: can't open file 'nosuchfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$ python nosuchfile.py^M
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

(the ^M above, I created by typing control-V control-M, where control-V is my "lnext" character).

The error message prints the file name, including the carriage return, and then the rest of the characters overwrite the initial part of the error.  Note that if you make the file name just a bit longer, you'll see part of it:

```
$ python verylongfilenamethatdoesnotexist.py^M
': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryamethatdoesnotexist.py
```

To fix it, open the crontab entry/file with an editor that lets you take out that bogus carriage-return.

Comment: And since the script has `#!/usr/bin/python`, it makes more sense to invoke it directly rather than passing it as an argument to the `python` command.

Comment: @KeithThompson: well, assuming `/usr/bin/python` is the correct path.  (My scripts mostly use `/usr/bin/env python` though I have had occasion to use a shell script front end to figure out which python to invoke, but that was at previous $work)

Comment: @torek Thanx this the problem i was saving cronjobs from webinterface to a textfile than coping the content of txtfile to crontab ,that's where i think i am getting carriage-return.